# how can I fix this code

Tags: c++

Somethings wrong with this code.I input “gender-m，age-20，tickets-10”
and it gives me 3200.It supposed to be 3500. I have no idea what's wrong with it, can you please help me? iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char gender;
int age, numTix, premium;

cout << "Enter your gender: ";
cin >> gender;

cout << "Enter your age: ";
cin >> age;

cout << "Tickets you have gotten: ";
cin >> numTix;

if (gender == 'M')
{
    if (age < 21)
    {
        premium = 1500 + 200 * numTix;
    }
    else if (age >= 21 && age < 30)
    {
        premium = 1200 + 100 * numTix;
    }
    else
    {
        premium = 1000 + 100 * numTix;
    }
}
else
{
    if (age < 21)
    {
        premium = 1200 + 200 * numTix;
    }
    else
    {
        premium = 1000 + 100 * numTix;
    }
    cout << "Your premium is $" << premium << endl;
}
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pay someone to fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

'm' is not the same thing as 'M'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is character case: you entered `m`, but your code is checking for `M`, which is an entirely different character.

There are two common way of fixing this:

- Call `topuuer` before the comparison, i.e. `gender = toupper(gender);` or
- Compare to both `m` and `M`, i.e. `if (gender == 'M' || gender == 'm')`

Answer (score 1):

Enter 'M' and not 'm'. Ascii values are not same for both and therefore else logic is being executed giving 3200.